# Optimisation - feasible points, regular points,Chong & Zak Q. 20.1

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

For this question from *Introduction to optimisation* by Chong & Zak :

> [image]

The answer is :

> [image]

What I'm unsure about is why $h$ and $g$ are not considered to be linearly
independent.

Is this because for the points in the feasible region we have

$$
x = [2, \alpha], \;\; \alpha \in [-\infty , -1]
$$

Then

$$
\nabla h(x) = [0, 0]^T
$$

and

$$
\nabla g(x) = [0, 3(x_2 + 1)^2]^T
$$

For the values of $x$ it is possible to choose $x_2 = -1$ then

$$
\nabla h = \nabla g
$$

meaning that, even though it isn't generally true, there is some value of $x$
for which we can express $\nabla h$ in terms of $\nabla g$.

If that isn't it then I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the feasible region, we have $x_1=2$, hence $\nabla h$ is identically $0$.

To verify linear dependence, simply note that $(1)(\nabla h) + (0)(\nabla g) = 0$.

Comment: So is the reasoning i gave correct?

Comment: Not exactly. Choosing $x_2=-1$ doesn't mean anything as far as the linear dependence of the gradients (since $x_2$ is not forced to equal $-1$). The argument I gave works for _all_ $(x_1,x_2)$ in the feasible region.